# Karnaugh map minimal representation

Tags: boolean-algebra

Find the minimal representation for:

$f(w,x,y,z)$ = summation $m(0,5,6,8,13.14)+d(4,9,11,12)$

I was a little confused what to do with the don't cares but I used all of them.

Based on the Karnaugh map I made $4$ groups:

$w'y'z'+y'z+wx'+yz'$

Then to simplify I factored out $y'$. So I got $y'(wz'+z)+wx'+yz'=y(w')+wx'+yz'$

Is this the minimal representation or can more simplification be done?

Comment: I have no idea what "f(w,x,y,z)= summation m(0,5,6,8,13.14)+d(4,9,11,12)" is supposed to mean...

Comment: what part of the question is confusing? Sorry for not asking it clearly.

Comment: The definition of $f$. The part I quoted. I have no idea what that means. What is the domain of $f$, and what is the definition of $f$?

Comment: that was all my textbook provided."f" represents the function we are trying to find the minimal representation for. Does that help? Since there are 4 variables and the karnaugh map goes up to 15.. so I would assume that is our domain?

Comment: What textbook is that?

Comment: Discrete and Combinatorical Mathematics by Grimaldi

Comment: @Lil What do the numbers $0, 5,7,8,13.14$ mean?!

Comment: they correspond to locations on the karnaugh map

Comment: $\begin{matrix}
0&1&3&2\\
4&5&7&6\\
12&13&15&14\\
8&9&11&10\\
\end{matrix}
-----
\begin{matrix}
m&m&·&·\\
d&m&·&m\\
d&m&·&m\\
m&d&d&·\\
\end{matrix}$

Comment: $\begin{matrix}
0&1&3&2\\
4&5&7&6\\
12&13&15&14\\
8&9&11&10\\
\end{matrix}
---
\begin{matrix}
m&·&·&·\\
d&m&·&m\\
d&m&·&m\\
m&d&d&·\\
\end{matrix}$

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $d(4,9,11,12)$ means that we don't care about these outputs.
You don't have to use all the don't cares.

If $f(A,B,C,D)$ is the given function with A the Most Significant Bit then the minimal representation is:
 
$$C'D' + BD' + BC'$$

Comment: yes d is the don't cares. So will using the cares such as I did prevent me form getting the minimal representation? I'm a little confused how to know if my solution is the simplest form.

Comment: So after creating the Karnaugh map I got xy'z+xyz'+w'x'y'z'+wx'y'z from there what simplification was done? 

Can I do: x(yz'+z')+x'y'(w'z+wz) ?

Comment: @Joker \\ Are you sure? I got ${\overline{C}\overline{D}}+{B\overline{D}}+{B\overline{C}}$.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi I went through the problem again on my own using the quine mccluskey algorithm but I got wx'z+y'z'+xz'+xy'z where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Joker I went through the problem again on my own using the quine mccluskey algorithm but I got wx'z+y'z'+xz'+xy'z where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\begin{matrix}
0&1&3&2\\
4&5&7&6\\
12&13&15&14\\
8&9&11&10\\
\end{matrix}
---
\begin{matrix}
m&·&·&·\\
d&m&·&m\\
d&m&·&m\\
m&d&d&·\\
\end{matrix}$